How to Skip Alternating Header Rows in CSV During FTP and ATP Integration in Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)?
I am working with Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) Generation 3 and need to process a CSV file that contains alternating header and data rows. The CSV file looks something like this:
id;name;age
1;John Doe;30
id;name;age
2;Jane Smith;25
id;name;age
3;Tom Brown;35
id;name;age
4;Alice Green;28

As you can see, the file has a header row followed by a data row, and this pattern repeats throughout the file. My task is to skip all the alternating header rows and process only the data rows (i.e., 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. rows should be skipped, while 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc. rows should be processed).
Here’s the workflow I’ve set up so far in OIC:

FTP Adapter: Download the CSV file.
Stage File Action: Read the file as a delimited file (semicolon ; as the delimiter).

Challenge:
OIC doesn’t seem to provide an out-of-the-box way to skip every alternate row. I understand that I may need to use JavaScript or some custom logic, but I’m unsure of how to efficiently implement this.
Questions:

How can I skip every alternate header row (e.g., rows 1, 3, 5, etc.) in OIC using JavaScript or any other method?
Is there a better approach to handle this scenario within the Stage File action or other OIC components?
Any detailed steps, code snippets, or guidance on handling this would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Information:

I am using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) Generation 3.
The CSV file contains 50 records with alternating headers and data rows.
The goal is to bulk import the data rows into an Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP) database.


You need use the Native format builder or other tools to define a Custom nxsd. Make use of Choice,ChoiceCondition & ChoiceValue construct or StartsWith Constructs of nxsd to handle the data conditionally.

Refer the link below :
About Native Format Builder and nxsd constructs.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/integration.1111/e10231/nfb.htm#TKADP2111
